# Show error on all cells having same value : WPF datagrid validation

Tags: wpf, validation, datagrid

I am having wpf datagrid where I have to restrict user from entering duplicate values. I am using IdataErrorInfo for validation. When I enter duplicate value in cell, it is highlighting only one cell which is currently I am modifying. But I want to highlight another cell having same value. Can any one please suggest any approach for this.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using binding??

Comment: Yes, model is binded with the view and model has IdataErrorInfo implemented